# os.rename saying cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a little useful script used to rename an mp3 file based on the tags of the song using `audio_metadata` library.

I already tried with `os.rename` and using `os.system('ren "FILENAME" "NEWNAME"')`.

My Code:

```
import os
import audio_metadata

for x in range(len(songs)):
    song = songs[x]
    metadata = audio_metadata.load('%s' % song)
    titlel = metadata['tags'].title
    artistl = metadata['tags'].artist
    title = titlel[0].strip()
    artist = artistl[0].strip()
    newname = '%s - %s.mp3' % (title, artist)
    print("[*] %s => %s" % (song, newname))
    os.rename(song, newname)
```

I expect:

```
your love.mp3 => Your Love-The Outfield.mp3
```

But I get this:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 
  'your love.mp3' -> "Your Love-The Outfield.mp3"
```

Comment: It sounds to me like another program is using the data...Have you checked in your task manager that nothing is in fact accessing it?

Comment: As the error states, something is already accessing the file. Maybe you have it open in a media player or in another part of your code?

Comment: I already checked and nope :l but thanks!

Comment: I think it might be your program that has the file open. Not sure if audio_metadata properly closes the file after extracting the metadata.

Comment: Sometimes just having an Explorer window open showing the directory where the file is can cause this.

Comment: @martineau Yeah that's correct me too ran into same problem
I was executing python script while explorer opening that file in notepad

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that `audio_metadata` is not properly closing the file object after reading when you call `metadata = audio_metadata.load('%s' % song)`? I took a quick glance at the  [audio_metadata source](https://github.com/thebigmunch/audio-metadata/blob/master/src/audio_metadata/api.py) and it looks like you can pass a file object instead of a filepath string.

Try getting the metadata this way instead:

```
with open('%s' % song, 'rb') as f:
    metadata = audio_metadata.load(f)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, it looks like it didn't worked out for me but **Thanks!**

Comment: I tried to duplicate your issue and with your original code and my update, and in both instances the file handle is left open and access is restricted. However, I tried `del metadata` before `os.rename()` and was able to rename the file. Will this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running through the VS debugger, I've run into a similar issue, and my solution was ensuring no other instances of my exe was secretly running in the background processes (as seen in the task manager). Ran into that issue when working with FMOD, not sure if that helps?

Comment: Thanks for the help, after considerating a lot of facts, I better decided to change the library to  [eyed3](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io) instead of `audio_metadata`

Comment: yeah that's good library better than audio_metadata